# How to set flag with phpmailer for outlook?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i want to set flag for outlook email which i am sending through phpmailer library.

followings are flags which i want to set.

1) Call
2) Follow up
3) For your Information
4) Read
5) Reply
6) Reply to all
7 Review

I am setting priority with this code

```
$mail->Priority = 1;
$mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: ".$m."");
$mail->AddCustomHeader("Importance: High");
```

so how can i set flags with phpmailer..

Thanks

Comment: For read receipt you can use Disposition-Notification-To: you@yourdomain.com but MSMail-Priority is used for high | low | urgent.

Comment: I am talking about flags not priority. i had already set priority.

Comment: Take a look at the headers of a mail using these features.

Comment: with Disposition-Notification-To: you@yourdomain.com i will know that email is read by user. right??

Comment: Don't just make up code and expect it to work - [read the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addCustomHeader). Also note that PHPMailer has built-in support for some of these things, for example [ConfirmReadingTo](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_ConfirmReadingTo) creates a `Disposition-Notification-To` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by me by this code priority and flag message

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: ".$m."");
$mail->addCustomHeader("X-Message-Flag: ".$flag."");
```